# Link style not setting for all links in CSS

Tags: html, css, styling

I'm slowly learning html/css. I have a client that wants 3 links on the page to be noticeable link colors (in this case, blue). However, when I try to edit the style of the links, only two of them are showing the changes.

[image: URL Links]

I can't set it globally, or other links (such as some social media icons) are changing.

Here is what I've tried:

```
div.entry-content a:link {
color: blue;
}

entry-content a:link {
color: blue;
}
```

Here is what I'm looking at when I inspect the page:

[image: Inspect Element]

So, where am I going wrong? I hope I added everything needed for assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming all three links are wrapped in in div with class entry-content. The only thing I can think of is that the first link is black or darker color because it's active or visited. You can style your links with just `a` selector or with additional pseudo selectors.

```
/* Just a selector */
.entry-content a {
    color: blue;
}

/* Just a selector */
.entry-content a,
.entry-content a:visited,
.entry-content a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: `entry-content` still needs to be a class selector: `.entry-content`.

Comment: @jerrylow That did it! :D I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have clicked on the link earlier, so the link status is active or visited.

Try this, if ok then update your code with pseudo selectors `:active` and `:visited`:

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a class name to the anchors, like so:
`<a class="blue" href="url">link text</a>` and then in your css create the blue class `.blue { color: blue; }`